# How to avoid unintended cell highlighting in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` set to multi selection mode, selection of entire rows. Works fine, only I get some kind of cell cursor I want to get rid off (row 71).

The following screenshot illustrates what I mean:
[image: Cell Cursor]

The rows I select with the mouse are highlighted in blue (see 69). But when I move around with the cursor keys the cells are somehow highlighted (see 71, 1st column - bit hard to see but visible). Any idea what is causing that?

Qt 5.6.1, widgets style is FUSION, Win10

Comment: That highlight shows where the keyboard focus is. Pressing spacebar (de)selects that highlighted item. It is useful for users using keyboard to navigate your app. Would you share what is your motivation for hiding it?

Comment: Because I cannot edit or select a single cell, it is useless like it is. It should highlight the entire row (selection is set to entire rows only), that would make sense to me.

Comment: Check the `selectionBehavior` property (on `QAbstractItemView`). Default value is `SelectItems`. If you change it to `SelectRows`, it may do what you want.

Comment: `selectionBehavior` is set to `SelectRows` - that`s why the entire row is selected in 69 (by mouse). This is my point, highlighting single cells is confusing.